# Pycharm does not install tensorflow-gpu package

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pycharm, yolo

I'm working on training a neural network for object recognition (Yolo) in Pycharm Communty Edition 2019.3. I've run the training a few times and now I've added some new images to improve accuracy.
The fact is that I need to install tensorflow-gpu 1.15. I had this installation before, but I uninstalled it for a different version and now I'm not able to do a new installation. I am doing the installation using the Pycharm terminal with the following command: pip install tensorflow-gpu == 1.15. The process runs and the messages that appear are that the request has already been satisfied for all packages, but these do not appear. The message is this:
Requirement already satisfied: gast == 0.2.2 in c:\users\user-23\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu == 1.15)

[image: install]
[image: result install]
[image: packages]
[image: GUI Install]

He's looking for packages on this appdata path, but my packages are at c:\users\user-23\source\repos\yolo 3\venv\lib\site-packages.
I believe it is just a matter of configuration, but I don't know how to get around that problem.

Comment: You can just click the plus (`+`) sign in the upper-right corner of the table with packages on the last screenshot and install any package there, from a GUI

Comment: Yes, I already looked for that path too, however version 1.15 is not available through this path.